# Bagisto after social login cart is showing empty

Tags: php, laravel

I am using bagisto laravel e-commerce platform for one of my ecommerce project.
https://bagisto.com/en/

Social login works fine after integration but one of the major issue my customers facing is
when they add some items in cart as guest it shows correctly on checkout page when they try
to login with social platform login done successfully but cart goes empty.

If any one has done this let me know.

Answer (score 0):

After digging a into files I found the solution for this issue.
Please check below my notes.

1. go to folder project/packages/Webkul/SocialLogin/src/Http/Controllers
2. Open LoginController.php
3. replace below code with your existing one

   ```
   /**
   * Handles callback
   *
   * @param  string  $provider
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
   public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
   {
     try {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->route('customer.session.index');
    }

    $customer = $this->customerSocialAccountRepository->findOrCreateCustomer($user, $provider);

    auth()->guard('customer')->login($customer, true);

    //STARTs - Cart Merge - 9mar21
    $cart_merge = Cart::mergeCart();
    $cart = Cart::getCart();

    $check_product_count = (isset($cart->items_count)) ? $cart->items_count : 0;
    if($check_product_count > 0){
        return redirect('checkout/cart');        
    }
    //ENDs - Cart Merge - 9mar21

    return redirect()->intended(route($this->_config['redirect']));
   }
   ```